# Retrieve DropDownList value in RowUpdating event asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, updating

Here is my aspx code:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTotalColumn" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Value="">Select value</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">1</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="1">2</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

My aspx.cs code:

```
protected void gvTest_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow selected_row = gvTest.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    var total_column_drop_down_list = (DropDownList)selected_row.FindControl("ddlTotalColumn");

    int column_string = Convert.ToInt32(total_column_drop_down_list.SelectedItem.Value);

    gvTest.EditIndex = -1;
    ...
}
```

At this line: int column_string = Convert.ToInt32(total_column_drop_down_list.SelectedItem.Value);
I have an error: "Input string was in incorrect format" because "total_column_drop_down_list.SelectedItem.Value" will return empty string ("").

So is there any bright idea?

Comment: Please noted that I call updating event after choosing value 1 or 2 in DropdownList

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have made the classic mistake of not putting your databinding code inside a `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` block.  Thus, your GridView re-binds, and you get default values in your RowUpdating event (rather than what you selected).

Wherever you are binding your GridView, in Page_Load for instance, you need to do this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    BindGrid();
}
```

Where "BindGrid()" is whatever code you call to databind your GridView.

---

On a slightly unrelated note, you can actually use the [GridViewUpdateEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter that's passed to that method to grab the updated values (rather than using FindControl to get the DropDownList, and then getting the values).

Comment: Do you have a code snippet to do that? I am trying to solve that exact issue.

Comment: @htm11h Code snippet to do what?  Get the values from the GridViewUpdateEventArgs object?

Comment: Check out the docs, @htm11h.  There's a good example at the bottom of using the .NewValues collection to get what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx